# Ubuntu 18.04 can't start nautilus or terminal

Tags: nautilus, google-chrome, password, gnome-terminal, remote-desktop

This started happening after I installed Chrome Remote Desktop. In addition, my Google Chrome forgot all of my information and I have to type in all my passwords, sync my bookmarks, etc. Ubuntu's password manager also says `Key manager wasn't unlocked on log in` and makes me type my password for the Ubuntu password manager, even though I just logged into my account. I'd like to uninstall Chrome Remote Desktop, because it seems to have been the problem, but I can't open Terminal. I've tried using the shortcut and `CTRL+ALT+T` and launching it from the start menu.

When I do launch terminal, I can see it in my System Monitor
[as seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pq4l8.png) but I can't actually see it, and it closes after a while.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You are in trouble, google took over your machine... just kidding. I think your terminal may be open in a virtual workspace what is not the one you are seeing. Have you try login from console to do the uninstall? You can switch to virtual console via CTL-ALT with a function key F2 to F6. In 18.04, F1 and F2 are used by the desktop.

Comment: Ah thank you so much, I didn't realize that I could switch virtual desktops like that. Chrome Remote Desktop must have been playing around with them in a bad way. I was able to uninstall it and fixed the problem, thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Bernard said in a comment above, the windows were opening on another virtual desktop. Switching to my 3rd virtual desktop with `CTRL+ALT+F3` let me uninstall the Chrome Remote Desktop package from the shell `sudo apt remove chrome-remote-desktop`.

Google may have taken over my machine, but Linux is strong enough to recover when the user can learn to control it :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have been experiencing this weirdness the whole day

Comment: this fixed my issue with the terminal and file manager only opening during boot on ubuntu 19.04 once and then not reopening again. Thank you

Comment: you are gods ;-)
two weeks with that problem ! solved !