# Nautilus does not launch in Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: nautilus, gnome-shell, 19.04

Some time after upgrading to Ubuntu 19.04, I have become unable to launch nautilus by double-clicking it and also unable to launch using terminal.

Output of `which nautilus`

```
/usr/bin/nautilus
```

Output of `apt-cache policy nautilus`

```
nautilus:
Installed: 1:3.32.0-0ubuntu2
Candidate: 1:3.32.0-0ubuntu2
Version table:
*** 1:3.32.0-0ubuntu2 500
    500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco/main amd64 Packages
    100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Output of `nautilus`

Does not give any output, it hangs there itself and does not give any output.

**UPDATE**

Output of `sudo nautilus -q`

```
** (org.gnome.Nautilus:4911): WARNING **: 03:46:22.268: Error on getting      connection: Failed to load SPARQL backend: Could not connect: Connection refused

(org.gnome.Nautilus:4911): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 03:46:22.281: g_dbus_connection_signal_unsubscribe: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_CONNECTION (connection)' failed

(org.gnome.Nautilus:4911): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 03:46:22.281: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

(org.gnome.Nautilus:4911): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 03:46:22.281: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

(org.gnome.Nautilus:4911): libunity-CRITICAL **: 03:46:22.373: unity-launcher.vala:157: Unable to connect to session bus: Could not connect: Connection refused
```

Comment: Not a bug, it happens to you because something in your system is broken. What errors does it show when you try to run from command?

Comment: Please add output of `which nautilus` and `apt-cache policy nautilus` to the question. Do you use GNOME session? What console output do you get when try to launch `nautilus` command in the terminal?

Comment: @N0rbert I have added the output, please have a look.

Comment: Try reinstalling nautilus. `sudo apt install --reinstall nautilus`. Also, do confirm the output of `which nautilus` that you've pasted. It doesn't look what it should be like.

Comment: I have updated output of `which nautilus`, thanks for pointing out. Also after some time I restarted my system and it is now working correctly. This happen earlier also. Don't know what is the reason

Comment: Try reinstall of nautilus.

Comment: Try removing nautilus conf and share: `rm -Rf ~/.conf/nautilus ~/.local/share/nautilus` and see if it works again.

Comment: @RoVo No, this does not work.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In my 18.04 setup I had problems with tracker causing the same issue, nautilus not launching, then it worked by killing tracker, but now that did not work either.

What did work, was resetting tracker. I performed a hard reset, you might try a soft reset, maybe it could work too, I didn't test, since it got fixed by the hard reset. Sidenote: I disabled search in files.

tracker hard reset in terminal :

```
tracker reset -r
```

tracker soft reset :

```
tracker reset -e
```

Comment: i tried killing the tracker once. and once that is done, no nautilus whatsoever.
now it seems ok after these pair of commands.
will monitor once i restarted the computer

Comment: Thanks! Working beautifully on 19.04

Comment: I tried it and It had been a week I am got no problem until now. Marking it as accepted answer. Thanks @Bart .

Comment: This answer help me solve an identical issue in Ubuntu 22.10, but using Tracker 3 - https://askubuntu.com/a/1453883/71473

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem. All was good in the  beginning, but after some time I was unable to open Files to access to my folders.

Try cleaning your operating system with Bleachbi:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install bleachbit
```

Run Bleachbit and clean your OS, then restart the computer.

This worked for me.

Comment: This does not work in my case.

Comment: This worked for me. And I didn't have to restart my computer.

Comment: @LeonardoCastro What things have you cleaned using bleachbit?

Comment: @MohitMalik Everything available, except stuff for which the program showed a warning like "this option is slow" or something.

Comment: @LeonardoCastro I did for that too, but still that does not solve the problem. My nautilus after sometime is automatically fixed, I don't know how. But the main problem is that it still stops launching many times after.

Comment: Indeed, the problem appeared again on my computer and BleachBit didn't solve it anymore. It's fixed after some time here too. It looks like something related to Dropbox initialization. Do you have Dropbox installed?

Comment: @LeonardoCastro No, I don't have Dropbox installed.

Answer (score 0):

I had an identical observation. I updated to 19.04 and then noticed sporadic behave with folders and the terminal. I would click the home folder and the busy icon would appear for a few seconds but sadly the home folder would not open. I would try to open a terminal (quick keys and through apps) but seemingly nothing happened. Then everything worked after a couple of restarts, with none of the methods tried on this thread, before reverting back to not working.

After searching for a more substantial answer than the ones provided on this thread I believe that I found a more plausible solution on another thread. I uninstalled Google Remote Desktop, and everything appears to be working robustly now (I even had old pages open that I had not seen since I installed Google Remote Desktop):

[Ubuntu 18.04 can't start nautilus or terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1050761/ubuntu-18-04-cant-start-nautilus-or-terminal)

Comment: I did not have Google Remote Desktop installed. So, it could not be the issue in my case. The accepted answer worked for me at first, but the problem comes back.  So, the idea that it is another application that creates the conflict is valid. It's just not Google Remote Desktop in my case. It's perhaps a dependency of Google Remote Desktop, which I require because of another application, perhaps even another Google application.