# Nautilus does not launch anymore after update to 22.10

Tags: nautilus, 22.10

Since I've updated my OS to 22.10, Nautilus does not launch anymore.

I can launch it in terminal with

```
sudo nautilus
```

but with a warning :

```
** (org‧gnome.Nautilus:5826): WARNING **: 08:31:26.276: Unable to get contents of the bookmarks file: Erreur lors de l’ouverture du fichier /root/.gtk-bookmarks : Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
** (org‧gnome.Nautilus:5826): WARNING **: 08:31:26.277: Unable to get contents of the bookmarks file: Erreur lors de l’ouverture du fichier /root/.gtk-bookmarks : Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
```

Without "sudo", it doesn't work :

```
emeric@DellUb-Pawouet : ~ $ LANG=en_US.UTF-8 nautilus
Failed to register: Timeout was reached
```

*edit*
[Adding here output of Strace nautilus](https://gist.github.com/e-riff/253edb9f2bdeb814c31ee7ea99d878aa)

I've already tried some stuff :

- reinstall nautilus with or without purge
- reset of tracker
- python réinstallation
- killall process of nautilus...

Waiting to fix it, I've installed Nemo.

Comment: Please, run the app as `LANG=en_US.UTF-8 nautilus` to have messages in English. Other than that, I'd try running it under strace as `strace nautilus` to perhaps try to see what it may time out on.

Comment: Thanks, I'm editing my first post with messages in english : emeric@DellUb-Pawouet : ~ $ LANG=en_US.UTF-8 nautilus
Failed to register: Timeout was reached

Comment: Output of strace nautilus added in original post

Comment: I'm curious if you're running Wayland (windowing system) or X11.  I've saw quite a few issues when running Wayland, switched back to X11 and all those issues were resolved.  
Check Settings...About...Windowing System
A switch to X11 may fix your issue.

Comment: I've used the two windowing system (switching at session start). Same problem on both :(. X11 is the one I use the most (Wayland has compatibility isues with Discord screen sharing)

Comment: New info, nautilus work if I change user

Comment: I have the same problem with the same error message. Did you find a solution by now?

Comment: Hey ! it's working again since yesterday \o/.I don't know why exactly. I've done a new time some steps I done before, but this time it worked. I think deleting nautilus folder (in home) manually and restarting completly the computer make the trick. I don't know why it didn't work first time. Do nautilus launch if you create a new user ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did in ~:

```
rm -rf ./.local/share/nautilus ./.config/nautilus
```

And this fixed the problem

Comment: I have the same issue, but this doesn't solve it for me. Can you confirm this is a effective solution?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, what solved it to me was the answer in https://askubuntu.com/a/1150219/71473 but using Tracker 3

```
$ tracker3 reset -s
```

**Update**: looks like this isn't a permanent fix, I have to run this command every time I boot the computer.

**Update 2**: yesterday I run

```
$ tracker3 reset -r
$ tracker3 reset -s
```

and today I didn't had to run any command for nautilus to behave correctly. <s>So this seems to be the permanent solution</s>.

**Update 3**: I'm still looking for a permanent solution...

**Update 4**: the problem looks fixed for a few weeks now as of 12th June 2023. Don't know how or why...

Answer (score 1):

I've updated today.
Had the same problem.
Done a "killall nautilus" and then it worked.
(But had to do it several times yet)
Cheers.